# How do you delete a GitHub pull request requested review?

Tags: rest, github

How do you delete a GitHub pull request requested review? This is about **deleting the request for review** on a pull request, not the pull request itself. I can't find a way using the website.

I also tried using the [REST API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/review_requests/#delete-a-review-request):

```
curl -i -X DELETE -u cherryblossom000 https://api.github.com/repos/<repo owner>/<repo name>/pulls/<pull number>/requested_reviewers -d '{"reviewers":["reviewer name"]}'
```

but I get this error:

```js
{
  "message": "Validation Failed",
  "errors": [
    "Could not add requested reviewers to pull request."
  ],
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/review_requests/#delete-a-review-request"
}
```

The GraphQL API doesn't seem to have a mutation to delete a review request either.

Comment: I think you [can't delete a pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318097/delete-a-closed-pull-request-from-github), you can only [close it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385567/how-to-cancel-a-pull-request-on-github).

Comment: @GinoMempin I'm talking about deleting the request someone to review the pull request, not deleting the actual pull request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too had this problem and also got several "Validation failed" messages. So I figured it might be because I didn't have direct permissions on the repo.

After emailing Github developer support, they confirmed that you can delete (or dismiss) a review request, provided you have **direct permissions** on the repository.

In conclusion, your REST API approach is correct. You only get the "Validation failed" message if you do not have direct permissions on the repo.

Comment: Could you clarify what does direct permission mean here? Is write permission on repo enough?